# Jupyter stop running in the middle of code sometime

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tornado, jupyter, windows-server

I run the python code on AWS ubuntu instance via Windows Server built on aws.
No problem until below code but jupyter sometime stop running from below code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.subplot('121')
plt.imshow(np.argmax(train_label[2].transpose(1,2,0), axis=2)
plt.subplot('122')
plt.imshow((train_label[2].transpose(1,2,0)*255).astype(np.uint8))
plt.show
```

When I run the code after stopping the kernel, sometime there is no problem until the end of the code.

Erro codes are as below:
[error code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss5Dz.png)

[error code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7UPt.png)

[error code 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOJWF.png)

Python version info are as below:

> Version: 3.5.2

[python ver info 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAIlr.png)

[python ver info 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrdCi.png)

[python ver info 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5exB.png)

Probably this is jupyter bug but not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: sorry attaching image instead of code which is hard to see. i can neither download code nor even copy & past since i'm using client's cloud env.

Comment: first error is this: ERROR: tornado.general uncaught exception, closing connection